# Node.js & WebSockets - forward WebSocket connection?

Tags: node.js, websocket, forward

I'm writing a server in Node.js that accepts WebSocket connections from clients. On connection, the client sends a JSON Web Token to authenticate. If the server successfully authenticates the user, I would then like to subscribe the user to a message broker (that accepts WebSocket connections).

My question is, how do I transfer the WebSocket connection between server & client to between message broker & client? 
Is this possible to do without exposing the message broker publicly, that is, only connections can be made that are transferred from the server - clients cannot make direct connections themselves with the broker?

Comment: It depends on how exactly you have implemented your WS server, but it may be possible to use something like [`websocket-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket-stream) to provide a sort of proxy between client and broker (after authentication by your server).

Comment: I'm worried that if I proxy all client-broker traffic thru my server that I'll slow the whole system down. Would it impact performance?

Comment: It would have _some_ impact, but Node is pretty good in dealing with I/O (hundreds to thousands of connections shouldn't be a big problem). If you don't want to expose the message broker to the outside world, proxying seems to be the only solution to me.

Comment: @robertklep any idea how to use something like websocket-stream to provide a sort of proxy between client and broker?

Comment: @AeroWang I haven't tried, but it might be as simple as creating a new connection to the destination server/broker using `websocket-stream` and piping the incoming websocket connection (from the client to your server) to it. Very similar to the _Usage_ code here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket-stream#usage (only replace `process.stdin/process.stdout` by the incoming client socket).